# Do you need to delete widget after removeItemWidget from QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17, qtreewidget

I have a `QTreeWidget` with two columns: one for property name and one for property value. The value can be edited via a widget. For example one property is Animal. When you double click the property value column I make a (custom) combobox with different animal types via this code:

```
QTreeWidgetItemComboBox* comboBox = new QTreeWidgetItemComboBox(treeItem, 1); 
// treeitem is a pointer to the row that is double clicked
comboBox->addItems(QStringList() << "Bird" << "Fish" << "Ape");
ui.treeWidget->setItemWidget(treeItem, 1, comboBox);
```

When the row loses focus I remove the widget again (and the value is put as text of the `QTreeWidgetItem`). For removing I use

```
ui.treeWidget->removeItemWidget(treeItem, 1);
```

Now I'm wondering, since I've used `new`, do I neww to also `delete` the widget. I know this is the case if you use `takeChild(i)` for example. But I didn't see something similar for an itemWidget.

Do I need to delete it what would be the right order?

```
QTreeWidgetItemComboBox* comboBox = ui.treeWidget->itemWidget(treeItem,1); 
// Do I need a cast here since the return type is QWidget*
ui.treeWidget->removeItemWidget(treeItem, 1);
delete comboBox;
```

or

```
QTreeWidgetItemComboBox* comboBox = ui.treeWidget->itemWidget(treeItem,1); 
// Do I need a cast here since the return type is QWidget*
delete comboBox;
ui.treeWidget->removeItemWidget(treeItem, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explaination

You **should not** manually delete a widget, added to a [QTreeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html), since it is **automatically deleted** either by

- destructing its parent tree widget

This is a direct consequence of the Qt's parent-child mechanism.

- calling `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget` anytime the tree widget still lives.

This one is not so obvious, since the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#removeItemWidget) simply sais:

> Removes the widget set in the given item in the given column.

However, looking at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreewidget.h.html#419) it becomes pretty clear what is indeed happening, i.e.

1. `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget` calls `QTreeWidget::setItemWidget` with a `null` pointer (no widget)

   ```
   inline void QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
   { setItemWidget(item, column, nullptr); }
   ```
2. [`QTreeWidget::setItemWidget`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreewidget.cpp.html#_ZN11QTreeWidget13setItemWidgetEP15QTreeWidgetItemiP7QWidget) in turn calls `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`

   ```
   void QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column, QWidget *widget)
   {
       Q_D(QTreeWidget);
       QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget(d->index(item, column), widget);
   }
   ```
3. Finally [`QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView14setIndexWidgetERK11QModelIndexP7QWidget) checks if there is already a widget at this index, and if there is one, calls its `deleteLater` method

   ```
   if (QWidget *oldWidget = indexWidget(index)) {
       d->persistent.remove(oldWidget);
       d->removeEditor(oldWidget);
       oldWidget->removeEventFilter(this);
       oldWidget->deleteLater();
   }
   ```

Simply put (and this should be made clear in the documentation of both methods of `QTreeWidget`), **any call to `QTreeWidget::setItemWidget` or `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget` deletes the widget (if any) already set for the item**.

## Example

Here is a simple example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate the described behaviour:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QPushButton>

struct MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
        auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
        auto *button = new QPushButton(tr("Remove combo box"), this);
        auto *comboBox = new QComboBox();

        comboBox->addItems(QStringList() << "Bird" << "Fish" << "Ape");
        treeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 0, comboBox);
        l->addWidget(button);
        l->addWidget(treeWidget);

        connect(comboBox, &QComboBox::destroyed, [](){
            qDebug("The combo box is gone.");
        });

        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [treeWidget, item](){
            treeWidget->removeItemWidget(item, 0);
        });

        resize(400, 300);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

## Result

The described ways of destroyng the widget could be tested with the application

[image: Application window with a button and a combo box in a tree widget]

- Simply closing the window destroys the tree widget together with its child combo box, hence the combo box's destroyed signal is emitted and the lambda prints

`The combo box is gone.`

- After pressing the button the lambda function connected to its `clicked` signal is called, which removes the combo box from the tree widget. Because the combo box is deleted (automatically) as well, the lambda from the second `connect` statement is called, which also prints

`The combo box is gone.`

Comment: Oh right, the source code indeed call `deleteLater()` on the old widget. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: I upvoted your answer since this is the one that should appear at the top :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to delete the item widget as the tree is the owner of the widget once it has been passed to the tree with `setItemWidget()`.

From the documentation of `setItemWidget()`:

> Note: The tree takes ownership of the widget.

**EDIT**: In case you want a new widget, simply call `setItemWidget()` once more or call `removeItemWidget()` in case you do not need the widget anymore. The tree will ensure that no memory gets lost.

Comment: So what do you mean? Can I not even do ```removeItemWidget()```?

Comment: Furthermore, I ```new``` every time an treeWidgetItem is double clicked so will that not raise memory problems?

Comment: @C.Binair `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget()` will not delete the widget. If you have no use of it, you can write `comboBox.deleteLater();` right after removing it from the parent `QTreeWidget`.

Comment: @Fareanor, _`QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget()` will not delete the widget_ This is not true. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @C.Binair,  _I new every time an treeWidgetItem is double clicked so will that not raise memory problems_ Each time you set a new widget, the old one is deleted. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

When the widget is added ot the `QTreeWidget`, it indeed takes ownership of the widget. But **it only implies that the widget will be deleted when the parent is destroyed.**

So if you just want to remove the widget while keeping the parent `QTreeWidget` alive, you indeed have to delete it manually.

The correct solution is the first one, remove the widget from the `QTreeWidget` first, and then delete it with one of the following ways:

```
delete comboBox;
comboBox = nullptr;
```

or:

```
comboBox.deleteLater();
```

The second one is preferred.

---

**EDIT:**

*I don't change the answer since it could be a dishonest to change what was already accepted, ...*

But as ***@Scopchanov*** mentioned, by reading the source code, the `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget()` already calls the `deleteLater()` method on the old widget. We don't have to do it manually.

Anyway, [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) says it is safe to call `deleteLater()` more than once:

> **Note:** It is safe to call this function more than once; when the first deferred deletion event is delivered, any pending events for the object are removed from the event queue.

Therefore, manually deleting the widget after calling `QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget()` becomes useless.

Comment: One additional question. I need to retrieve the pointer to the widget. If I do: ```QTreeWidgetItemComboBox* comboBox = ui.treeWidget->itemWidget(treeItem,1); ``` I get an error that a value of type ```QWidget*``` can not be used to initialize an entity of type  ```QTreeWidgetItemComboBox*```. Should I use a cast or should I just write ```QWidget* comboBox = ui.treeWidget->itemWidget(treeItem,1); ```? With pointers i'm never super sure about the type in such cases

Comment: @C.Binair It depends. If you need to access `QTreeWidgetItemComboBox` specific methods, you'll need to do a cast (`qobject_cast<QTreeWidgetItemComboBox*>(ui.treeWidget->itemWidget(treeItem, 1))` for example).

Comment: No I only want to delete it. So then using ```QWidget*``` would be just right I guess

Comment: @C.Binair Since the destructors are `virtual`, you can use polymorphism, so yes, you can directly delete the widget without casting it.

Comment: @C.Binair I have edited my answer since I made a mistake. Just in order to not let you be in error with what I said :)